# Passing Enum as parameter

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this method,

```
private List<SelectListItem> GetList()
{
    var values = from LtlAccountType item in 
                 Enum.GetValues(typeof(LtlAccountType))
                 select new SelectListItem 
                 { Text = item.ToString(), Value = item.ToString() };
    return values.ToList();
}
```

How to pass `enum` as `parameter` and return list after querying the `enum`

```
private List<SelectListItem> GetList(Enum obj)
{
    var values = from obj item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(obj))
                 select new SelectListItem 
                 { Text = item.ToString(), Value = item.ToString() };
    return values.ToList();
}
```

I got this error on `obj`

`Type or namespace name expected`

Comment: `typeof()` works for types. When you have an instance, call for example `obj.GetType()` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

[Starting from C# 7.3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-3#enhanced-generic-constraints) you can use `System.Enum` as a type constraint.

---

You should call `GetType()` instead of use `typeof()`. Also you cannot use `Enum` as a base class of any enum. The best solution is to use `struct`...

```
private List<SelectListItem> GetList<T>(T obj) where T : struct
{
    var values = from Enum item in Enum.GetValues(obj.GetType())
                 select new SelectListItem { Text = item.ToString(), Value = item.ToString() };
    return values.ToList();
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error on `GetType()` as `Cannot access non-static method GetType in static context`

Comment: @DON I'm sorry. It's ok now :)

Answer (score 1):

That's because `obj` is not a valid type identifier in .NET. Why don't you do a simple

```
List<SelectedListItem> result = new List<SelectedListItem>();
foreach (var item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(obj)))
   result.Add(new SelectedListItem() { Text = item.ToString(), Value = item.ToStringt() }

return result;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just tried this and it works:

```
private static List<SelectListItem> GetList(Enum item)
{
    var values = from Enum e in Enum.GetValues(item.GetType())
                 select new SelectListItem { Text = e.ToString(), Value = e.ToString() };
    return values.ToList();
}
```